# Show commits made on branch originally (filter out merged commits)

Tags: git, filter, merge

In a git repo with several branches, I've merged a feature branch into master and merged back from master into the feature branch. **How can I now use `git log` see only those commits made on the feature branch?** I need to filter out those comments made to other branches, even though they've been merged back into this feature branch.

```
$ git status
On branch some_feature

$ git checkout master
$ git merge some_feature
$ git checkout some_feature
$ git merge master

$ # Lots of coding and days gone by

$ git log --some_magic_here
```

If it matters, the machine on which I'd like to run `git log` is not the same machine that was used to code the feature. I need this feature to perform a **code review** on another developer's work. Filter by `author=SomeDev` doesn't help as I am reviewing one specific feature branch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR: you want `--first-parent` (see [`git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html)) and a few other selection criteria.

Git does not keep track of "on which branch a commit was actually made".  For instance, suppose you are on branch `B` and you do this:

```
$ git checkout --detach B
[message about "detached head"]
[edit some file here, and git add result]
$ git commit -m message
$ git branch -f B HEAD
$ git checkout B
```

This will add a new commit to the tip of branch `B`, even though the commit was made while not on a branch at all.  Or, suppose there are two branches `B1` and `B2` that both point to commit `C7`:

```
... <- C5 <- C6 <- C7   <-- B1, B2
```

If you make a new commit `C8` whose parent is `C7`, then make branch `B2` point to `C8`, that commit is now on branch `B2`.  If you made the new commit while on branch `B1` then `B1` also points to `C8`, but if you then use `git reset` to move `B1` to point back to `C7`, it is no longer possible to tell<sup>1</sup> that the commit was originally made on `B1` rather than `B2`.

All that said, if you maintain good consistency when you merge branches, you can perform graph traversals on the commit graph, finding commits "between" particular merges, and then working through one particular parent chain, to detect which branch the commits were *probably* done-on.  For instance, with `feature` and `master` as described, suppose that commits are consistently made on `feature` and then `feature` is periodically merged into `master` with `--no-ff` so as to make sure that each merge-commit on `master` is a true merge commit, and not merely a fast-forward.  Then the graph pattern will look something like this:

```
... --X--*------*-o---o-----*--*   <-- master
       \       /   \       /  /
        A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H     <-- feature
```

(where "time" increases as one moves right, and the `*` nodes are the merge commits made on branch `master`, with `o` nodes representing other commits on master).

In this case, you can find commits that were (probably) made on `feature` by starting with the tip of `feature` (commit `H`) and traversing only first-parent commits—these are `A` through `H`—and then discarding commits findable by following only first-parent commits on `master`.  This second criterion eliminates the commit marked `X` above (and any preceding commits).  (Note that in the case of merge commit `E`, its *first* parent is `D`, and its *second* parent is the `o` commit above it to the left on `master`.  For all the merges on `master`, the *first* parent is on the same line, and the *second* parent is below and to the left on `feature`.)

Whether this is sufficient depends on how disciplined you (and others) have been in the commit process.  If `master` has its own internal branch-and-merges, you may have a graph more like this:

```
... --X---Y---*-----*-o---o---------*--*   <-- master
       \   \ /     /   \           /  /
        \   Z     /     \         /  /
         \       /       \       /  /
          A--B--C--D------E--F--G--H       <-- feature
```

Now you can't just use the first/not-first parent test quite as easily, since commit `Y` or `Z` is necessarily the second parent of a merge on `master`, but note that `Z` is not reachable from `feature` without first traversing `E`, which is a merge commit "directly on" `feature` whose second parent commit is on `master`.

In other words, I use the slightly peculiar phrase "directly on" a branch to identify commits that are find-able by starting at the branch tip, and working backwards through first parent only.  For `feature` these are (still) `A` through `H`, plus unfortunately `X` and its (first) parents.

The `git rev-list` command, which is one of git's very central commands—it's kind of the big-sister version of `git rev-parse` which is also very central—has a flag that specifically implements this "directly on" notion, namely, `--first-parent`.  The rev-list command walks<sup>2</sup> through some part(s) of the commit graph: you tell it some commit to start from, and it finds that commit's parents, and those parents' parents, and their parents, and so on.  If you specify `--first-parent` it finds only the *first* parent of each commit.  (This obviously affects only merge commits, since by definition a non-merge commit has at most one parent commit.)

In your particular case, you have also said that you wish to eliminate merges *into* your `feature` branch, i.e., merge commits that are directly on `feature`.  To do this, simply tell rev-list to exclude merge commits from its output, with `--no-merges`.

Eliminating commit `X` and earlier is a bit harder, but as it turns out, not *that* hard provided you know which branch(es) contain commits like `X`, that you want to exclude, are on.  The `--not` argument (including several alternative spellings) tells rev-list what commits to *exclude*.  So:

```
git rev-list --first-parent feature --not master --no-merges
```

identifies the list of commits "directly on" feature (`A` through `H`) but *not* directly on `master` (`X` and earlier), and then lists only those that are not merges (thus eliminating commit `E`).

You will probably want to pare this down further, e.g., perhaps by using commit time stamps (`--since` and `--until`).  You may (or may not) want to change the order in which revisions are listed as well, perhaps using `--topo-order` to put them in graph order rather than date order, for instance.

#### Putting this together with `git log`

Fortunately for you, `git log` effectively invokes `git rev-list` with your revision specifiers.  So instead of having to use `git rev-list` first, then somehow feeding the results to `git log`, you can just give these same specifiers to `git log`.  In fact, when figuring out which limiters you want (with things like `--since` and `--until`), `git log` is a lot easier to work with, as a big pile of raw SHA-1s are not very useful to humans.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, the reflogs, which keep a history of branch motions, do give you the ability to tell, but only on the one local machine; the question said that this must be done on a different system, where the reflogs are not available.  In any case the reflog entries expire after a while, 90 days by default for the ones of interest here.

<sup>2</sup>Unless, of course, you use `--no-walk`.

Comment: Thank you, this was quite informative and sent me down paths that I would not have tried!